# How does one solve questions in Montiel's Curves and Surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have currently opted for a course titled Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces for which my instructor is referring to Montiel and Ros' Curves and Surfaces. Having finished Chapter 1, I am still not getting how to solve the exercises given. For example:

(18) Let $\alpha:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ a curve parametrized by arc length (p.b.a.l) with positive curvature.Then $\alpha$ is an arc of a circle if and only if it has constant curvature and it's trace is contained in a sphere.

From where should one start to solve such problems?

Comment: You should replace "p.b.a.l." by the exact words.

Comment: Could you also define “trace”?